# Receiving a lot of noise with RTL-SDR and SDR# for GOMX-1

Tags: antenna, software-defined-radio, rfi, rtl-sdr, sdrsharp

Hi im new to SDR and having issues setting up SDR#. I'm trying to receive from GOMX-1 on 437.25 MHz for a project. My set up is the dongle, a LNA and a self built helical antenna for that frequency's measurements. I managed a couple of very noisy signals earlier this week but since haven't been able to re do it let alone improve on that. I've put a screenshot of the interface below - any support or advice would be most welcome!

[image]

I have previously received from NOAA using the dongle so the dongle is ok.

Comment: Hi Rob, welcome to the site! Can you share a little more about the antenna, specifically what mechanism you use to keep it pointed at the satellite?

Comment: plus, as long as you're not saturating, you can increase the RF gain – that would decrease the noise figure. I don't personally use SDR#, but I bet you can reduce that filter bandwidth to quite exactly your signal of interest, too!